# Length of returned list does not match length of vector from which the iterator is retrieved when using foreach in R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I am trying my hand at parallel processing in R using the foreach package but it is not working as I want it to. I am using a function I created myself (`Xenopus_Walk`) which returns a vector. Now I would like to run this function for every number that is saved in a vector (`newly_populated_vec`) and obtain a list that stores a every vector that has been created as one element of said list. The command I am currently using is the following (I guess you can ignore most of it since that's mostly only exported packages and parameters my function relies on):

```
no_cores <- detectCores()-1
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl) 
Xenopus_Data <- foreach(b=1:length(newly_populated_vec),.combine=list,.multicombine=TRUE,.packages = c("raster", "gdistance", "rgdal","sp")) %dopar% { Xenopus_Walk(altdata=altdata,water=water,habitat_suitability=habitat_suitability,max_range_without_water=max_range_without_water,max_range=max_range,slope=slope,Start_Pt=newly_populated_vec[b]) }
```

The problem I have now is that the length of the returned list (`Xenopus_Data`) si different from the length of the vector I retrieve the iterator from (`newly_populated_vec`):

```
> length(Xenopus_Data)
[1] 47
> length(newly_populated_vec)
[1] 2027
```

While trying to figure out what is wrong I have read that one has to split up the workload into equal chunks and pass each of them to a core but as you probably can tell my understanding of all this is pretty low. I am have a total of 32 cores at my disposition. 
Does anyone know why I have this problem and maybe also a way to solve it ? I know that reproducible examples are desired, but the function I use is pretty long and I doubt anyone is going to work through it. Still, if I can help make things clearer by providing additional information I will be glad to do so!
Any type of help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I forgot to add that when I look at the list it is nested, so I don't get one element for every number in the vector but I get one element with multiple sub-elements. Just in case that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `.combine=list` since that will result in a nested list if there are more than 100 results (unless you specify a larger value using the `.maxcombine` option). I've seen that used before, but I'm pretty sure it is always done due to a misunderstanding of how the `.combine` function works.

The default behavior is to return all of the results in a list, so you can fix the problem by simply removing the `.combine` and `.multicombine` options.

Here's a simple example that demonstrates this:

```
> length(foreach(1:2027, .combine='c') %do% 1:10)
[1] 20270
> length(foreach(1:2027, .combine=list, .multicombine=TRUE) %do% 1:10)
[1] 47
> length(foreach(1:2027) %do% 1:10)
[1] 2027
```

Using the default `.combine` function, the result is always a list whose length is equal to the number of tasks specified, regardless of the type of the results.

---

In case you're interested, here's how you can explicitly define and use a combine function that works just like the default combine function:

```
library(foreach)
# This is defined the same as "foreach:::defcombine"
listcomb <- function(a, ...) {
  # concatenate new results with list of all previous results
  c(a, list(...))
}
r <- foreach(1:101, .combine='listcomb', .init=list(),
    .multicombine=TRUE, .maxcombine=100) %do% {
  list()
}
```

Note that you must specify `.init=list()` so that the first argument to `listcomb` is an empty list the first time that `listcomb` is called. If you don't do this, the first result will be corrupted if it happens to be a list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! I know about the combine option, but the problem is that I need to further analyze the results and therefore I need every vector as a single object. If I paste all vectors together in one big vector I won't  be able to retrieve them like I would be if they were stored in a list.

Comment: @snoops The default behavior is *not* to paste all vectors together into a single vector. The default is to return each result as an element of a list. It only concatenates the results if you specify `.combine="c"`.

Comment: Ok, I thought that since the default setting is to store the output of the function in a list it wouldn't make any difference whether I type `.combine="list"` or not. Apparently I was wrong :) Thanks again for helping me out !